# GTK+ themes on Arch GNOME

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, gnome3, gtk, theme

So I'm trying to install [this](https://github.com/horst3180/Arc-theme) theme onto my laptop along side dash-to-dock (dash-to-dock works fine). I can't, however, get the theme to work on my user account. It works on the root account, but I would rather not use that for day-to-day use for obvious reasons. I've tried doing everything with sudo, restarting the shell after installation, and rebooting but it refuses to work. It does appear in gnome-tweak-tool but selecting the theme does not apply it like it does on the root account; gnome-tweak-tool is being run with sudo.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme <theme>
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme <theme>
```

does not fix it either

gnome-tweak-tool shows that I have selected that theme even after rebooting, so it is clearly changing something. However, `screenfetch` shows the GTK theme as Adwaita - the default.

It just seems odd that it works fine on the root user but not on the admin user account while using sudo.

GNOME version 3.16.3

Kernel: i686 Linux 4.1.4-1-ARCH

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is weird, I did what don_crissti said and ran 'gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme' which printed 'Adwaita' as expected. But after that, I ran 'gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme Arc-Darker which now works. After a restart, which I had already tried before.

Thanks for helping